# Powershell: Get ONLY the value from an object

Tags: powershell, encryption, bitlocker

This is most likely going to be a very simple fix but its something I am trying to get my head around when it comes to the `select` keyword. How do I simply return the value 'On' from the below script:

```
$bitlockerStatus = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer {Get-BitLockerVolume | select ProtectionStatus -First 1}

$bitlockerStatus
```

It returns:

```
ProtectionStatus PSComputerName RunspaceId                          
---------------- -------------- ----------                          
On               MKC-06981      *confidential*
```

I have used the `select` statement before to return the value but I cant understand why in this case it isn't working. I need it to return 'on' or 'off' so I can use it in a String comparison.

Thanks

Comment: Using [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration): `(Get-BitLockerVolume).ProtectionStatus`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter with `Select-Object` to expand just the value of a particular property:

```
... |Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProtectionStatus -First 1
```